# can I run ggraptR from a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I recently saw the ggraptR R package which starts a shiny app to allow interactive data visualization. I would like to use this package since it offers generic plotting functionality.

My dataset selection process depends on interactive input from user (where the user is given a set of choices from a DB query result) and I need another shiny app to accomplish this goal. My question is: can I start ggraptR with this fetched dataframe within the existing shiny session?

My guess is this would not be possible as there is only one shiny instance allowed at a given time. Am I correct or is there a work around?